# How can I layout text and inputs on a form to fit a specific width (justified)?

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

I have a form and I am trying to make a row "justified" so the entire row (which is a 4 textboxes and labels) to fit an exact pixel width (lets say 800px).  Normally, if i just lay it out without any special css, It is less than 800px.  I want to "stretch" it to be 800px.  I don't care if I have to stretch the textboxes or the spaces in between them.

This is similar to justified layout in MS word if that helps describe what i am looking for.  Is this possible within html / css in a form layout?

Comment: Or could you supply a layout image?

Answer (score 5):

You basically need [`text-align-last: justify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-align-last) which specifies the justification of the "last text line" in a block element, this defaults namely to the standard direction, which is `left` in LTR.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 15994654</title>
        <style>
            #fields {
                width: 1000px;
                border: 1px solid gray;
            }

            .justified {
                text-align-last: justify;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="fields" class="justified">
            <label for="input1">label1</label>
            <input id="input1" />
            <label for="input2">label2</label>
            <input id="input2" />
            <label for="input3">label3</label>
            <input id="input3" />
            <label for="input4">label4</label>
            <input id="input4" />
        <p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works in IE and Firefox (for older Firefox versions, add `-moz-text-align-last: justify` if necessary), however this fails in Webkit based browsers (Chrome/Safari). To cover those browser as well, you'd need to replace `.justified` as follows, so that the last line doesn't appear as a "last line" anymore, so that `text-align: justify` can do its job the usual way:

```css
.justified {
    text-align: justify;
}

.justified:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Note that the `text-align-last: justify` becomes redundant this way.

Here's the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rj6aM/).

Comment: Brilliant solution, using the `:after` pseudo-element. +1

Comment: In your solution the `text-align-last: justify;` rule is redundant: it will try justifying an element that's already at it's maximum width.

Comment: @lolmaus: well spotted, it becomes indeed redundant this way. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's a very natural way to do this with pure CSS using `text-align: justify;`.

You didn't succeed because justification doesn't work for the last line (and when there's only one line, it's considered to be the last). There's a CSS3 property that sets text alignment for the last line: [text-align-last](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-align-last). Unfortunately, it is not broadly supported.

The solution is to spawn an extra element that will drop to next line, then the first line will be justified:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" value="" />
  <input type="text" value="" />
</form>
```

```css
form {
  width: 800px;
  text-align: justify;    /* Can we really make this work? Sure! */
}

input {
  display: inline-block;  /* making elements respect text-align */
}


form:after {
  content: "";            /* creating a hidden element that drops to next line */
  display: inline-block;  /* making it respect text-align and width */
  width: 100%;            /* forcing it to drop to next line */
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ituroj/5/ (click "edit" in top right corner to fiddle with the code).

Result: semantic, no HTML footprint, minimal CSS code, full browser support.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be:

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or, if the fields are really inside a `<table/>` like in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se6Fu/1/), you can set the `width` of the textboxes to `100%`, so the table controls the width:

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by nesting the input and labels inside of 'columns' that you determine the width of by percentage - this way you can control the width of the form and the inputs will stay justified.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="col4">
        <label>Input</label>
        <div class="inputWrapper">
                <div class="textInput">
                    <input type="text"/>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col4">
        <label>Input</label>
        <div class="inputWrapper">
                <div class="textInput">
                    <input type="text"/>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col4">
        <label>Input</label>
        <div class="inputWrapper">
                <div class="textInput">
                    <input type="text"/>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col4 last">
        <label>Input</label>
        <div class="inputWrapper">
                <div class="textInput">
                    <input type="text"/>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form{
    width:800px;
}

.col4{
    width:23.5%;
    margin-right:2%;
    float:left;
}

.last{
    margin:0;
}

.inputWrapper{
    width:100%;
}

.textInput{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
}

.textInput input{
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    padding:0;
}
```

You can see a jsFiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/patricklyver/4mbks/

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `float` with `box-sizing`. You will have to float, because forms have different weirdness around them in different browsers. For example in Safari on OS X there is always a hidden 1px padding on the top.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/XjbeW/)

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#myForm {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 800px;
}

#myForm input[type=text] {
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: orange;
}

#myForm .clear {
    clear: both;
}
```